# Variable url desaparece al iniciar seccion

Tags: php5

estoy con un problema debido a mi falta de experiencia en programación.

Estoy haciendo un instructivo en donde indico los paso a seguir para bajar documentos de una seccion de la web. Ejemplo `http://localhost/ciec/documentos.php?id=17`. Al llegar a esta url, programé que sólo usuarios registrados del sitio pueden acceder a la misma.

El asunto es que cuando inicio sesión la variable `?id=17` desaparece y queda la url `http://localhost/ciec/documentos.php` y en consecuencia da el error que la variable id no está definida.
Si me pueden orientar de como resolver este dilema AGRADECIDO.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Para futuras oportunidades, una pregunta sin código es imposible de responder de forma oportuna. No teníamos cómo saber cómo estabas produciendo la URL

Comment: perfecto. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a este dilema estaba el el archivo session habia que cambiar esta linea

```
$this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

por esta

```
$this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```